# Search for a package to generate graphic displays of calculators

Tags: packages, plot, draw, technical-drawing

My question it is very simple: I have seen that there are several packages like, [Graf35](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/graph35/graph35-fr.pdf), and [Casio ClassWiz font](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/casiofont/casiofont.pdf).

Is there any package that could generate this kind of drawing? I remember to have seen one like it some time ago, but I don't remember the name of the package.

[image]

Comment: It's not pixelated like yours but I liked [tipfr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipfr), see page 11. CTAN also has [ticollege](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ticollege).

Comment: You could try the [LCD package](https://ctan.org/pkg/lcd?lang=en). It defines an extended alphanumeric character set, with each character constructed using dots set in a 5 x 7 matrix, mimicking an LCD display. See [How to transcript codes from HP 50G in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394832/) for an example.

Comment: @DJP Thank you very much for your contribution to my application. I don't know where you've seen it these years... but in my mind I remember seeing something similar. I sometimes like to use something that is old.

Comment: @Ross I reciprocate also to you from the bottom of my heart for contributing your comment. The same considerations valid for the comments included to all users.

Comment: @Sebastiano You said, "I don't know where you've seen it these years..."; the original post on tipfr is from 2015 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/draw-calculator-keys-with-latex/220282#220282)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really explain why but I find this topic quite fascinating. To gather more information you could search CTAN:

## Suitable packages

The search for [calculator](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=calculator) yields

- Package [`calculator`](https://ctan.org/pkg/calculator)
  Use LaTeX as a scientific calculator
- Package [`ticollege`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ticollege)
  Graphical representation of keys on a standard scientific calculator
- Package [`tipfr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipfr)
  Produces calculator's keys with the help of TikZ
- Package [`graph35`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graph35)
  Draw keys and screen items of several Casio calculators

Then there is the keyword lcd which only yields one usable package:

- Package [`lcd`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lcd)
  Alphanumerical LCD-style displays

## Other TeX.SE answers

- [How to improve calculator code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459084/220875)
- [Mimicking a calculator inputs and screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290321/220875)
- [Draw calculator keys with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220281/220875)
- [Calculator style base 10 notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70528/220875)
- [A collection of the actual smartphones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479840/220875)
- [Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40095/220875)
- [How to transcript codes from HP 50G in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394832/220875)
- [Pixelated font as on Texas Instruments calculators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37538/220875)

That's all I could find so far. As you can see, there are many different ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and the links you attached to me. In my mind I remember seeing something similar but I do not remember nothing.

Comment: @Sebastiano, don't worry, I really had fun collecting the links. Can't wait to see what you come up with. Please do post your results!

Comment: I have it in my mind that I saw something but I don't remember... thank you very much.